# Increasing array size dynamically in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need to increase length of 2 arrays according to user input. I'm using the code below. But output is not matching with user input.

```
    #include<stdio.h>        
    int main()
    {
        int i=0, key=0, size[key], time[key];

        while (key!=-1)
        {
             printf("Insert value for size : ");
             scanf("%d",&size[i]);
             printf("Insert value for time : ");
             scanf("%d",&time[i]);
             i++;

             printf("Run again Press-1 or Exit  : ");
             scanf("%d",&key);
        }

        int x=0;
        for (x ; x<i ; x++)
        {
             printf("%d %d\n",size[x],time[x]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

When user inputs the values:

```
    35 4
    20 3
    40 1
    60 7
    20 8
```

Then this is the output:

```
    8  4
    20 3
    40 1
    60 7
    20 8
```

If length of array exceeded 4, the last element of the `time` array will be printed as the first element of the `size` array.

Why does my program give this output?

Comment: That's not how any of this works. Look up `realloc()` if you want to allocate a resizeable array.

Comment: What part of your code do you think is defining the initial size of these arrays, and what is that size?  What part do you think is changing that size?

Comment: Also, size[key] and time[key] are declared when key is zero, meaning there are no items available in the array, it's zero size. I'd expect your program to crash

Comment: How do I use realloc() function?

Comment: You use `realloc` to change the size of memory allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @pistachiobk array dimensions do not need to be constants. However using `0` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @M.M  As I read C11 spec `malloc(0)` is Unspecified behavior, not undefined behavior.  "Whether the `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc` functions return a null pointer or a pointer to an allocated object when the size requested is zero" §J.3.12

Comment: @chuk I refer to `int key = 0, size[key];` as in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to get you started.

Use `realloc()` to re-size the memory pointer to by a pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>        
#include <stdio.h>        

int main(void) {
  // Start with NULL and a size of 0
  int *my_time = NULL;
  size_t sz = 0;

  while (!some_exit_condition) {
    long long ll; 
    printf("Insert value for size : ");
    if (scanf("%lld", &ll) != 1) {
      puts("Numeric input missing");
      break;
    }
    if (ll < 0 || ll > SIZE_MAX) {
      puts("Size out of range");
      break;
    }

    sz = (size_t) ll;
    void *new_ptr = realloc(my_time, sz * sizeof *my_time);
    if (new_ptr == NULL && sz != 0) {
      puts("Out of memory");
      break;
    }
    my_time = new_ptr;

    // do something with `my_time` and `sz`

  }
  // Clean-up
  free(my_time);
  my_time = NULL;
  sz = 0;

  return 0;
}
```